# How to let threads manipulate the same list Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an class where I define a list with an add and deletion method like here:

```java
public class listClass{
    private List<T> someList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(){
        //adds to list
    }

    public void delete(){
        //deletes from list
    }
}
```

I have another class where I define two threads and a object from where I can access my list. One thread should use the add method to add continuously to the list and another thread should use the delete method to delete continuously from the list respective to there thread numbers:

```java
public class threadClass extends Thread{
    private int threadNumber;
    public ThreadClass(int threadNumber){
        this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
    }

    listClass listClassObject = new listClass();

    public void run(){
        if(threadNumber == 1){
            while(true){/*add*/}
        }
        else if(threadNumber ==2){
                while(true){/*delete*/}
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that so that both threads manipulating one and the same list?

My current implementation has a different class with a main method where I call the threads like here:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        threadClass threadForAddingMediaFiles = new threadClass(1);
        threadClass threadForDeletionMediaFiles = new threadClass(2);
        threadForAddingMediaFiles.start();
        threadForDeletionMediaFiles.start();
```

The problem with the current implementation is that every thread creates his own instance of the list (which is clear to me because the list is in the same class) and so every thread does manipulate his own list and not one universal list.

Comment: First, create a single instance of `ListClass` and pass it to each instance of `ThreadClass` (by the way, notice I'm using `CamelCase`, as is conventional for class names in Java). Then make sure you synchronize on an object (could be `someList` or the instance of `ListClass` itself) so that the needed _happens-before_ relationships are created.

Comment: What does it mean to have a single instance of `ListClass`? How do I do this? @Slaw

Comment: In `ThreadClass` you have `ListClass listClassObject = new ListClass()`. That's creating an instance of `ListClass` at the same time as when an instance of `ThreadClass` is created. But you are creating **two** instances of `ThreadClass` (in the `main` method), which means ultimately this code results in **two** instances of `ListClass` being created. Don't do that. Create a single instance of `ListClass` and pass it to the constructor calls of `ThreadClass` (you'll have to add a parameter). See the first and second code blocks in [paolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72150208/6395627).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that happens because you are instantiating a new listClass inside each threadClass object so when you modify the list, you are actually modifing in each thread their own "local" copy.
Try to instantiate the list in your main function and then pass it to your threads, so you'll have a single instance of your list class manipulated by both your threads.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    listClass myList = new listClass();
    threadClass threadForAddingMediaFiles = new threadClass(1, myList);
    threadClass threadForDeletionMediaFiles = new threadClass(2, myList);
    threadForAddingMediaFiles.start();
    threadForDeletionMediaFiles.start();
```

Then modify your thread implementation:

```
public class threadClass extends Thread{
private int threadNumber;
private listClass listToHandle;
public ThreadClass(int threadNumber, listClass listToHandle){
    this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
    this.listToHandle = listToHandle;
}

public void run(){
    if(threadNumber == 1){
        while(true){/*add*/}
    }
    else if(threadNumber ==2){
            while(true){/*delete*/}
    }
}
}
```

Finally remember to to put both your add and delete method in your listclass as synchronized, or you'll have some problems regarding concurrent access.

```
public class listClass{
private List<T> someList = new ArrayList<>();

public synchronized void add(){
    //adds to list
}

public synchronized void delete(){
    //deletes from list
}
}
```

You may also give a look to [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), which is a thread-safe implementation of ArrayList. However, as said in the docs, this is ordinarily a costly implementation and might be not a suitable solution for your problem.

Comment: What does thread-safe mean?

Comment: Being thread-safe it's the property that guarantee that your object behaves correctly in the case of multiple executions by multiple threads. If an objects is not thread safe and multiple threads access to a shared resource, it may expose erroneous behavior or produce unpredictable results.

Comment: @rhymes That's a complicated subject. But essentially, unless you explicitly write the code otherwise, the Java specification does not guarantee that changes done by one thread will be "seen" by another thread. To guarantee such changes _are_ seen by other threads you need to create a _happens-before_ relationship. This is described in more detail in the [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) of `java.util.concurrent`. To be "thread safe" is to have ordered _happens-before_ relationships.

Comment: You create these relationships via mechanisms just as `synchronized`, `volatile`, the classes in `java.util.concurrent.locks`, and so on. Some classes, such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, are written in a thread-safe way so that you don't have to do much on your end (unless you're doing more complicated operations, such as "check-then-act" stuff).

Answer (score 0):

In modern Java, we rarely address the `Thread` class directly. Instead, use the Executors framework added to Java 5. This has been covered in many existing Questions and Answers, so search to learn more.

Define your tasks as a `Runnable` rather than a `Thread`.

As for sharing your list manager across threads, make one instance. Be sure your list manager is thread-safe. Your current implementation is not thread-safe. One solution would be marking both the add and delete methods as `synchronized`.

Pass the one instance of your list manager object to the constructor of your `Runnable` task objects. Each `Runnable` keeps a reference to that list manager as a private member field. All your runnables then share the same single list manager.

Submit all your `Runnable` objects to an `ExecutorService`.

Again, all this has been covered many times already. Search to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.synchronizedList() then no need to add synchronous into add/delete method. Create an instance of the ListClass and then pass it to both constructors of 2 threads.

```
class listClass
{
      private List<T> someList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());    
}
```